# Data from Firebase Not showing in BigQuery/Data Studio

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Have linked Firebase with BigQuery so I can display IOT data from Firebase to a Data Studio report.

When adding a new data source, I can and select the project as follows:

My project > project name > DataSet (Displays:firebase-crash-analytics,firebase-messaging,firebase-predictions.

However, the data collected(through an IoT device) in firebase is not showing up as a dataset.[1]

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAi6r.jpg "data not showing"

- adding new data(in firebase), and/or upgrading account from sandbox (BitQuery)

Would expect to make the Firebase data as a data source within Data Studio report(Through BigQuery as it appears to be the only way)

Comment: What specific Firebase product(s) have you linked to BigQuery?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen its a database (real time Database).

To make the integration I performed the following steps; select project > project settings > Integrations >BigQuery

Answer (score 0):

If you check the Firebase console for [integrations with BigQuery](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/settings/integrations/bigquery), you'll see that it currently contains toggles fpr Analytics, Crashlytics, Predictions, and Cloud Messaging.

This means that there is no automatic integration between the Firebase Realtime Database and BigQuery at the moment. If you want to store data from the database into BigQuery, you'll have to write the integration yourself with the APIs from both products.